# How to write one file at a time in Java

Tags: java, file, int

Here is my code

```
static void filewrite() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    File f;
    for (int i = 0; i <=1000000000; i++) {
        f=new File("myfile" + i + ".txt");
        if (!f.exists())
            try {

                f.createNewFile();
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);
                fileWriter.write(dateFormat.format(date));
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("File Written");
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to write a file that contains the date, but I only want it to create one file each time I call the function.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: what's the output of your code? btw. for clarity you miss { (bracket) after if (!f.exists())

Comment: yes, I fixed that. My code outputs about 10 million files

Comment: use brackets everywhere, especially after line ```if (!f.exists())```

Comment: @pbielicki That makes no sense. He only knows how to name the file inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `break` is for. Note comment in code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=1000000000; i++) {
    f=new File("myfile" + i + ".txt");
    if (!f.exists()){
        try {

            f.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);
            fileWriter.write(dateFormat.format(date));
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("File Written");
        break; // <==== Break out of the for-loop
   } // if
} // for
```

For further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: close, but when I call the function again my program freezes instead of creating the next file

Comment: @Top-Bot Can you tell where exactly it "freezes" ? At which line?

Comment: Downvote? Seriously? I'd really like to know why. I am willing to improve!

Comment: I don't know, I upvoted because it was the correct solution.

Comment: Yes, someone else did. This happens sometimes. But they never leave a comment on why. It's not that I wouldn't appreciate criticism to improve this and future answers ...

Comment: That is my biggest complaint with this site, this is a place to come ask questions and receive answers. there should be a rule that you have to comment why if you downvote

Comment: I believe there is a discussion on meta about exactly that request.